# How can I get the Postgres port

Tags: postgresql

I just installed Postgres newly and I try to check if its running and on what port, although I know what default port it normally has
these commands are not showing me the port.

```
service postgresql status
```

I get this

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor prese
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-09-18 14:17:14 CEST; 22min ago
  Process: 2632 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2632 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Sep 18 14:17:14 user-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Starting PostgreS
Sep 18 14:17:14 user-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQ
Sep 18 14:39:19 user-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQ
```

And when I just try to simply check process and see what port it shows this after the command

```
 sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2592/postgres   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1065/postgres_expor
```

How can I get the port to show and what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, find the “postmaster” process, the parent of all other PostgreSQL processes.

You can get it from the `postmaster.pid` file in the PostgreSQL data directory if the database is started.

Then you can get the port with `lsof`. Assuming the process ID is 23521, run

```
lsof -P -sTCP:LISTEN -i TCP -a -p 23521
```

That will show you the port where PostgreSQL is listening.

Answer (score 10):

[This answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/573327/779409) needs you to connect to the machine and no other packages or root user.

Just connect and run the command.

> If you can connect to PostgreSQL from the original machine you can see what port it's listening on:

SHOW port;